# If there existed an eighth Snow White's dwarf gone missing, and he worked as a programmer, what would he be called like?

Tags: translation, suffix

I've been discussing this topic with a friend of mine. Most of them in my native language (Italian) end with `olo`, for instance *Sleepy* becomes *Pis**olo***, *Grumpy* becomes *Bront**olo*** and so on, kind of like most of them end up with `y` in English, to convey a sense of smallness and/or helplessness.

So I was wondering, what would its Korean equivalent be, applied to the specific case in which he worked as a programmer. Bonus if you can also provide a ninth (female) dwarf who works as a shop assistant.

Comment: what is your level of Korean and what have you tried to find the answer to this?